# why is 'list index out of range' showing?

Tags: python, list, range, traceback

```
n = int(input())
students = list()
for i in range(0,n):
    students[i][0]=input("Name: "); students[i][1]=float(input("Grade: "))
```

I wrote this code but 'list index out of range' is showing. I don't understand why it is happening.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-966bd0f334a2> in <module>
      1 n = int(input())
      2 for i in range(0,n):
----> 3     students[i][0]=input(); students[i][1]=float(input())

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please Help.

Comment: `a` is an empty list. So it has no `a[0]` to assign to.

Comment: What is inside `students`?

Comment: Sorry I have to edit again. It is my first question so I apologize. Here student[i][0] should store student name and students[i][1] should store grade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that you're trying to assign `students[i]` when `students` is an empty list. Similarly, you're trying to assign `students[i][0]` and `students[i][1]` when `students[i]` doesn't even exist!

The solution is simple: Instead of assigning to the list (`x[1] = 3`), append to the list (`x.append(3)`).

```py
n = int(input())
students = list()
for i in range(0,n):
    students.append([]) # Must add empty list otherwise students[i] doesn't exist
    students[i].append(input("Name: ")); students[i].append(float(input("Grade: ")))
    
print(students)
# Prints [['a', 1.0], ['b', 2.0], ['c', 3.0]]
# after inputting 3, a, 1, b, 2, c, 3
```